# Android - It is possible to get latitude and longitude using NetworkProvider for current location without internet connection?

Tags: android

There is any way to get current location's latitude and longitude without internet connection( Mobile Data Off and Wifi Off) using only NetworkProvider. I know we will get last known location which is previously tracked. But, I need to get updated current location's latitude and longitude.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is an illogical question.In this case GPSprovider can work but Name itself says network must requires to get location from NEtworkProvider

Comment: u can get last known location !! without internet connection :-
mLocation=locationManager   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surly we get the latitude and longitude without internet connection.

```
LocationManager lm;
lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location net_loc = null;
net_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//net_loc.getLatitude(); net_loc.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 try {
                LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    LocationListner mListner = new LocationListner();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                try {
                                    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListner);
                                } catch (Throwable e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListner);
                            } catch (Throwable e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListner);
                            } catch (Throwable e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


public String getLatitude() {

        Location loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (loc == null) {
            loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (loc == null) {
                loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (loc != null) {
                return "" + loc.getLatitude();
            }
        } else {
            return "" + loc.getLatitude();
        }
        return "0";
    }

public String getLongitude() {

        Location loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (loc == null) {
            loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (loc == null) {
                loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (loc != null) {
                return "" + loc.getLongitude();
            }
        } else {
            return "" + loc.getLongitude();
        }
        return "0";
    }
```